# ActiveRecord - Compare two values in same row

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table of call data and I want to query all unanswered calls, which means that the call start time is equal to the call end time. I currently use the following plain SQL which works as expected:

```
select * from calls where calls.start = calls.end
```

I was wondering if there is a more "rails" way to do this using the ActiveRecord Query Interface. Ideally I'd like to set up a scope in my `Call` model that returns me all unanswered calls. Something like:

```
scope :unanswered, -> { where(start: :end) }
```

The above doesn't work because Rails treats `:end` as a string instead of the `end` column in the DB.

I'm using PostgreSQL as my DB engine.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query

```
select * from calls where calls.start = calls.end
```

could be done in a `rails` way using a scope as follows:

```
scope :unanswered, -> { where('start = end') }
```

Comment: This didn't work exactly as stated, but when I do `scope :unanswered, -> { where('calls.start = calls.end') }` it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sure ... because it's in a scope. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

```
scope :unanswered, -> (end) { where(start: end) }
```

Comment: This means that you can provide a value in place of `end` which will be used in the scope. Doesn't quite solve my problem.