# ActiveRecord select by field comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to select records where two fields do not have equal values.
(where field A does not have the same value as field B). This involves alias_attributes. I would like to be able to use the alias names and not the cryptic database names so that the rails code can be isolated from the database names.

Model:

```
alias_attribute :item_amount, :fielda
alias_attribute :item_applied_amount, :fieldb
```

This codes works:

```
  query = where('fielda != fieldb')
```

But I'd rather have something like:

```
query = where.not(item_amount: item_applied_amount:)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActiveRecord - Compare two values in same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802782/activerecord-compare-two-values-in-same-row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO you cannot do that, because the database knows nothing about the aliases defined in your model.

Furthermore even if the aliases were working, `where(item_amount: :item_applied_amount)` would be translate to `fielda = 'fieldb'` in SQL. That means: The value of the `fielda`column must equal the string `"fieldb"` (not the value of the column `fieldb`)

But you can use `attribute_alias(name)` to get the original name and use the returned strings to build a proper query:

```
where(
  "#{attribute_alias(:item_amount)} != #{attribute_alias(:item_applied_amount)}"
)
```

Or you might want to define a scope to improve readablity:

```
scope :without_matching_amounts, -> { where('fielda != fieldb') }
```

and use it like this:

```
query = Model.without_matching_amounts
```

Comment: This is certainly more what I'm looking for and with a little modification it works fine and is understandable in its meaning. where("#{attribute_alias(:item_amount)} != #{attribute_alias(:item_applied_amount)}")

Answer (score 0):

Like @spickermann said, `alias` do a ruby method alias, does not create an alias in SQL.

What you can do is create the alias like :

```
scope :with_aliases, -> {
  select('table.*, table.item_amount as fielda, table.item_applied_amount as fieldb')
}
```

And then do something like:

```
Model.with_aliases.where('fielda <> fieldb')
```

Comment: Sorry if I failed to be clear enough. I'm trying not to use the cryptic names "fielda" and "fieldb" as they are not clear in what the field name represents. "fielda" does not tell someone that it represents "item_value" and is therefore hard to understand at first glance.